# How to fill list (row-wise, not column-wise) to select number of columns?

Tags: r

## Setup

I have a list with an odd number of objects.
For reproducibility, I provide dummy code below.

```
df <- as.list(c(1:67))
```

## Questions

1) How can I condense this list into 5 columns if the length is not divisible by 5?

2) How can I transpose the data to fill row-wise, not column-wise.

## Example

For example, what I had done in the past is this (using values divisible by 5)...

```
df <- as.list(c(1:65))
dim(df) <- c(length(df)/5, 5)
```

Which results in the following

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,] 1    14   27   40   53  
 [2,] 2    15   28   41   54  
 [3,] 3    16   29   42   55  
 [4,] 4    17   30   43   56  
 [5,] 5    18   31   44   57  
 [6,] 6    19   32   45   58  
 [7,] 7    20   33   46   59  
 [8,] 8    21   34   47   60  
 [9,] 9    22   35   48   61  
[10,] 10   23   36   49   62  
[11,] 11   24   37   50   63  
[12,] 12   25   38   51   64  
[13,] 13   26   39   52   65
```

If I try to do this with the odd numbered list I get this error

```
Error in dim(df) <- c(length(df)/5, 5) : 
  dims [product 65] do not match the length of object [67]
```

How can I make the result look like this (i.e. change the fill to row-wise and leave the last row with blanks)?

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,] 1    2    3    4    5  
 [2,] 6    7    8    9    10  
 [3,] 11   12   13   14   15  
 [4,] 16   17   18   19   20  
 [5,] 21   22   23   24   25  
 [6,] 26   27   28   29   30  
 [7,] 31   32   33   34   35  
 [8,] 36   37   38   39   40  
 [9,] 41   42   43   44   45  
[10,] 46   47   48   49   50  
[11,] 51   52   53   54   55  
[12,] 56   57   58   59   60  
[13,] 61   62   63   64   65  
[14,] 66   67
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `split`

```
library(rowr)
lst1 <- split(unlist(df), 
       as.integer(gl(length(df), 5, length(df))))
out <- t(do.call(cbind.fill, c(lst1, fill = NA)))
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [2,]    6    7    8    9   10
# [3,]   11   12   13   14   15
# [4,]   16   17   18   19   20
# [5,]   21   22   23   24   25
# [6,]   26   27   28   29   30
# [7,]   31   32   33   34   35
# [8,]   36   37   38   39   40
# [9,]   41   42   43   44   45
#[10,]   46   47   48   49   50
#[11,]   51   52   53   54   55
#[12,]   56   57   58   59   60
#[13,]   61   62   63   64   65
#[14,]   66   67   NA   NA   NA
```

---

Or after the `split`, pad `NA`s at the end based on the `lengths` of the `list` element and `rbind` it to a single `matrix` (`base R`)

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))
```